# How to create a border radius in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Help me to create border like this.

[image]

```css
.child::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  left: -1px;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  border-left: 0.5px solid;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid;
  border-left-color: #808080;
  border-bottom-color: #808080;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to describe the problem with your current code. What does it produce and how does it differ to what you want? Including a runnable snippet with HTML and your CSS would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help

```css
ul {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style: none;
}
 .main-ul {
     padding-left: 15px;
     position: relative;
}
 .main-ul:before {
     content: "";
     width: 2px;
     background: #ccc;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 15px;
     bottom: 35px;
}
 .main-ul label {
     padding: 15px 15px 15px 0;
     background: #ccc;
     display: block;
     margin-left: -15px;
     z-index: 1;
     position: relative;
}
 .main-ul .sub-ul li {
     position: relative;
     padding: 10px;
     overflow: hidden;
     padding-right: 0;
}
 .main-ul .sub-ul li:before {
     content: "";
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     border: 2px solid #ccc;
     border-radius: 15px;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0px;
     bottom: 50%;
}
 .main-ul .sub-ul li span {
     display: block;
     background: #fff;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1;
     margin-left: 15px;
     padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-ul">
  <li>
  <label>Chat Bots</label>
    <ul class="sub-ul">
      <li><span>Chat GPT</span></li>
      <li><span>Poe</span></li>
      <li><span>Openbot</span></li>
      <li><span>Chat GPT</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```